# Integrate a recommendation engine into a TYPO3 based website

Tags: json, rest, typo3, recommendation-engine

The main objective is to create a recommendation engine for an existing website running on TYPO3 CMS.

Development of recommendation engines is not a big issue.
The bottleneck is, it's integration into the TYPO3 CMS and I do not have much experience in dealing with web applications.

1. User history will be stored in local storage and not as a cookie.
   But this is taken care of in the TYPO3 side.
   History can be read and sent to the recommendation system in JSON format.
2. The RE interprets the JSON and retrieves article IDs and creates a final list of suggestions from a precalculated similarity matrix.
3. Thereafter the RE fetches the URL and title and sends the response in the form of a JSON file again.
4. TYPO3 receives this JSON and displays the result.

This is the rough outline I came up with.
Does this sound feasible?

Or is it better to think about getting recommendations as AJAX requests ?

**Note:**
This qs was edited with new ideas thanks to Aristeidis Karavas and Bernd Wilke.

Comment: The first question would be, “what do you know about TYPO3”? TYPO3 is complicated enough to start with. If you have no prior experience, then I would suggest you to start learning TYPO3 first, because sometimes it can be challenging. TYPO3 is PHP based, so i would strongly recommend to use PHP since TYPO3 has its own DATABASE queries it makes the search a game for kids.

Comment: To answer your question, I don't know much about TYPO3. My main objective is to build a recommendation engine and I am proficient in that kind of programming. However main question is how to integrate that to the CMS; for which you recommend learning TYPO3. But is there any specific topic I should start with ?

Comment: And when you recommend using PHP, do you recommend that the recommendation  engine be written in PHP ? I was more inclined towards Python especially because of the large variety of ML specific libraries available.

Comment: Your objective is proficient itself so I think you would pick it up real quick. The installation process (composer recommended) is something you need to first take care of. After that, the necessary configuration with TypoScript. Next, the process which TYPO3 works with to deliver the content. It is a normal MVC concept. And last, what you need the most and probably the solution to your current objective, is how to create extensions. Pretty straight forward but in case you need help, you can always use slack. There you can find all the help you need

Comment: https://typo3.slack.com/ Join the channel and we can talk there as well

Comment: depending where you want the recommendations to be integrated in the website  you could use different approaches. one way, which might be easier to you, could be: use AJAX to get the recommendations independent from page delivery. the AJAX requests could be served by python. on the other side: maybe the recommendation data is available in the TYPO3 data already (e.g. categories) and you might just need to connect it to the page generation (build a menu based on categories).

Comment: @Bernd Wilke πφ qs is do I need to create a TYPO3 extension for this ? Where exactly do i need to make the change in the CMS architechture ?

Comment: if you want a communication in TYPO3 (= that is the server) that would mean an extension. there are no plain scripts which can be included in TYPO3. It's no change in the architecture of TYPO3 (that would be very bad), it's a configuration or additional functionality. and that's what extensions are for. So: you build an extension which adds your recommendations while the form is build.

Answer (score 0):

After further discussion with a teacher and Aristeidis Karavas' answer, I came up with a rough outline for the implementation.
This is for future reference by anyone, who like me has limited knowledge about Web Application implementation.

1- Look for restful api python examples.

2- Make a simple one that receives a request with json payload that had one property 
{ name: ‘some name’ }

3- Return a response with json that holds one property where you say hello the received name.

4- Run the api and test with (Postman or rest client extension in chrome)

{ response : ‘hello name’ }

5- Import all your RE files in the api.

6- Replace the logic of saying ‘hello name’ with the logic of getting a history and returning a list.

This assumes that the RE algorithm has already been taken care of.